# pass data between Activities in my app

Tags: android, session, android-activity

I have a e-commerce app there will be a sign-out button on each activity.

I am thinking that for sign out i will pass the session id of the signed in user for sign-out. But i m not able figure out how to keep session id alive for all activities. Can anyone guide me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a SignOutActivity class and pass the session id to the SingOutActivity class using intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SignoutActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("SESSION_ID", sessionId);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in the  SignOutActivity access the intent and in this activity you can logout the user from the app.

```
String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID");
```

Answer (score 0):

Having different Signout button on each activity is a bad design practise.
Also Session id should be a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it two way.
First is shared preference: When user sign in set session id in shared preferences and check it value or in every activity. If it set correctly then allow user to process further otherwise auto sign out. If user click on sign out button unset shared preference value and redirect user to login screen

Second way is use global data class which hold session is. When user log in set session id in data class and pass it values with intent extra when use go one activity to another activity and match with global class values if all ok then allow user to do all tasks. When user click on sign out unset session id in data class.